# How do I remove white space between HTML nodes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I'm trying to remove whitespace from an HTML fragment between `<p>` tags

```
<p>Foo Bar</p> <p>bar bar bar</p> <p>bla</p>
```

as you can see, there always is a blank space between the `<p> </p>` tags.

The problem is that the blank spaces create `<br>` tags when saving the string into my database.
Methods like `strip` or `gsub` only remove the whitespace in the nodes, resulting in:

```
<p>FooBar</p> <p>barbarbar</p> <p>bla</p>
```

whereas I'd like to have:

```
<p>Foo Bar</p><p>bar bar bar</p><p>bla</p>
```

I'm using:

- Nokogiri 1.5.6
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails

#### UPDATE:

Occasionally there are children nodes of the `<p>`Tags that generate the same problem: white space between

**Sample Code**

Note: the Code normally is in one Line, I reformatted it because it would be unbearable otherwise...

```
<p>
  <p>
    <strong>Selling an Appartment</strong>
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>beautiful apartment!</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>near the train station</p>
    </li>
    .
    .
    .
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li> 
      <p>10 minutes away from a shopping mall </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>nice view</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  .
  .
  .
</p>
```

How would I strip those white spaces aswell?

## SOLUTION

It turns out that I messed up using the `gsub` method and didn't further investigate the possibility of using `gsub` with `regex`...

The simple solution was adding

```
data = data.gsub(/>\s+</, "><")
```

It deleted whitespace between all different kinds of nodes... Regex ftw!

Comment: Does your HTML contain tags besides `<p>` with embedded blanks, and do those also need to be stripped?

Comment: First of all, thanks for reformatting my question, it's allot better now :)

And yes, occasionally there are children tags such as: `<ul>` and `<li>` that should ideally be stripped...

Comment: Can you add some samples of the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags? Also, it's important to show a comprehensive sample of the data you're working with. When we only see a small subset it's too easy to come up with code that only handles that scenario instead of the whole picture.

Comment: updated it, and that seems reasonable...

Comment: Are you creating the source HTML or is it out of your control and you are trying to clean up someone else's mess? If you are in control of it, fixing the HTML generation is the right answer and a lot easier.

Comment: It is a huge mess but I'm saldy not in control of it... It's an XML Feed, which also contains messed up HTML

Comment: Turns out that I've been using the gsub method in a wrong way and worked out after all...

Still thanks for your help!

Comment: Seriously, regex isn't anywhere close to being capable of handling the task in a universal manner across XML from multiple sources. But, we all learn this lesson different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd write the code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<p>Foo Bar</p> <p>bar bar bar</p> <p>bla</p>
EOT

doc.search('p, ul, li').each { |node| 
  next_node = node.next_sibling
  next_node.remove if next_node && next_node.text.strip == ''
}

puts doc.to_html
```

It results in:

```
<p>Foo Bar</p><p>bar bar bar</p><p>bla</p>
```

Breaking it down:

```
doc.search('p')
```

looks for only the `<p>` nodes in the document. Nokogiri returns a NodeSet from `search`, or a nil if nothing matched. The code loops over the NodeSet, looking at each node in turn.

```
next_node = node.next_sibling
```

gets the pointer to the next node following the current `<p>` node.

```
next_node.remove if next_node && next_node.text.strip == ''
```

`next_node.remove` removes the current `next_node` from the DOM if the next node isn't nil and its text isn't empty when stripped, in otherwords, if the node has only whitespace.

There are other techniques to locate only the TextNodes if all of them should be stripped from the document. That's risky, because it can end up deleting all blanks between tags, causing run-on sentences and joined words, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: I'd be glad if you could check my updated question... The problem really frustrates me...

Answer (score 0):

A first solution can be to remove empty text nodes, a quick way to do this for your exact case can be:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<p>Foo Bar</p> <p>bar bar bar</p> <p>bla</p>")
doc.css('body').first.children.map{|node| node.to_s.strip}.compact.join
```

This won't work for nested elements as-is but should give you a good path for start.

UPDATE:

You can actually optimise a little with:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<p>Foo Bar</p> <p>bar bar bar</p> <p>bla</p>")
doc.children.map{|node| node.to_s.strip}.compact.join
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, and as I didn't need to adjust nested elements it is a great solution for me! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it suits your needs.

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to do this. It will run slower and slower as the HTML file size increases because it looks at *EVERY* node below `<body>`, not just the ones desired.

Comment: No, there wouldn't be an improvement. You're still starting at the top of the tree and walking through every node.

Comment: I agree, but as I use DocumentFragment.parse, the content of the document is only the desired HTML, therefore I want to check every node and a search would add unnecessary latency. Do you see any reason I could have overlooked why a search would make it faster?

Comment: @theTinMan Your solution obviously seems faster, about 4x in average : https://gist.github.com/ZenCocoon/5633669

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the possible task you can be looking for which deals with unnecessary whitespaces(including unicode one) in parsing output.

```
html = "<p>A paragraph.<em>&nbsp; &nbsp;</em> <br><br><em>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
</em></p><p><em>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </em>
</p><p><em>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; </em><strong><em>\" Quoted Text \"&nbsp; </em></strong></p>
<ul><li><p>List 1</p></li><li><p>List 2</p></li><li><p>List 3 </p>
<p><br></p><p><br><em> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</em><br>
A text content.<br><em><br>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </em></p></li></ul>"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)

doc.traverse { |node|
  # removes any whitespace node
  node.remove if node.text.gsub(/[[:space:]]/, '') == ''

  # replace mutiple consecutive spaces with single space
  node.content = node.text.gsub(/[[:space:]]{2,}/, ' ') if node.text?
}

# Gives you html without any text node including <br> or multiple spaces anywhere in the text of html
puts doc.to_html

# Gives text of html, concatenating li items with a space between them
# By default li items text are concatenated without the space     
Nokogiri::HTML(doc.to_html).xpath('//text()').map(&:text).join(' ')

#Output 
# "A paragraph. \" Quoted Text \"  \n List 1 \n List 2 \n \n List 3  \n A text content. \n \n"

# To Remove newline character '\n'
Nokogiri::HTML(doc.to_html).xpath('//text()').map(&:text).join(' ').gsub(/\n+/,'')

#Output
# "A paragraph. \" Quoted Text \"   List 1  List 2   List 3   A text content."
```

**Note:** If you are not using `fragment` in case of a complete `html` doc then you might have to replace `traverse` with other function like `search`.

Answer (score -3):

data.squish does the same thing and is way more readable.

Comment: String#squish does not remove white space between HTML tags